# Angular (click) not included in html when rendered, any idea?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to angular, the Angular (click) even though has added to the tag, but it doesnt show in webpage html, and I could't click it as expected. any idea of what happening here? Thanks

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { EventService } from "./shared/event.service";
import { ToastrService } from "../common/toastr.service";

declare let toastr

@Component ({
  template: `
  <div>
    <h1>Upcoming Angular Events</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor='let event of events' class="col-md-5">
        <event-thumbnail (click)="handleThumbnailClick(event.name)"
        [event]='event'></event-thumbnail>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})

export class EventsListComponent implements OnInit {
  events: any[]
  constructor(private eventService: EventService,
    private toastr: ToastrService){

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.events = this.eventService.getEvents()
  }

  handleThumbnailClick(eventName) {
      this.toastr.success(eventName)
  }
}
```

is there any wrong in the sequece of importing module?

```
@NgModule({


imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    EventsAppComponent,
    EventsListComponent,
    EventThumbnailComponent,
    EventDetailsComponent,
    NavBarComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    EventService,
    ToastrService
  ],
```

Error message showing in the console.

```
EventsListComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at m (toastr.min.js:1)
    at Object.i [as success] (toastr.min.js:1)
    at ToastrService.push../src/app/common/toastr.service.ts.ToastrService.success (toastr.service.ts:8)
    at EventsListComponent.push../src/app/events/events-list.component.ts.EventsListComponent.handleThumbnailClick (events-list.component.ts:34)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (EventsListComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js:11107)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:12204)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11907)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:8561)
    at core.js:9005
```

Comment: For your future reference.  Don't place screenshots of the code. Use ctrl + k and add your code in future

Comment: noted with thanks :)

Comment: Can you post the component code? This should work and the click event is not usually shown in the DOM which is fine. There must be another reason for the failure here.

Comment: sure, I have posted it

Comment: `(click)` doesn't go in DOM. Put some `console.log` or `alert` in the `handleThumbnailClick` and see if it is triggered on click

Comment: Hi @SaptarshiBasu, I just tried putting console.log in it, I thought I couldnt trigger it, how ignorance I am! I got some error message finnaly, could you help take a look?

Comment: The error is coming from `toastr.service.ts`. Please post the code of the service.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not click event. You are passing the event.name in the parent DOM. But *NgFor event is present in the child DOM. In Angular click event usually not shown in the DOM.

Comment: Hi, I have deleted the first (click) event in the div.row, now the *ngFor is the parent, but still cannot click it, could it be the import sequence problem? Thanks

Comment: event-thumbnail element is component with custom element tag, you cannot attach click event. Please attach it inside template property of Component. You can pass event object as input to the  'event-thumbnail' component.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the great help. the (click) event work finely, I found the problem from the package **'toastr'**. I **reinstalled** it, and import it in angular.json right under jquery was imported **(before was above jquery.js)**. and everything works fine now. thanks you everyone, happy coding :)